# Find a maximum matching that saturates a given set of vertices

Tags: graphs, bipartite-matching

In an unweighted bipartite graph $G = (X + Y,E)$, we would like to find a maximum matching, but among all those maximum matchings, we would like to find one that saturates a given subset $X_0\subseteq X$.

A necessary condition for the existence of such a matching is that $X_0$ satisfies Hall's marriage condition, i.e., for every $X'\subseteq X_0$, the number of neighbors of $X'$ is at least $|X'|$.
If this condition is satisfied, we can find a matching $M$ that saturates all vertices of $X_0$, but $M$ is not necessarily a maximum matching in $G$.

Is it always possible to extend $M$ into a maximum matching? Alternatively, is there a different way to find a maximum matching that saturates $X_0$ when the necessary condition is satisfied?

Comment: What happens if you additively boost the weight of each edge touching $X_0$ so that a maximum matching must contain the maximum number of such edges?

Comment: Do you mean to assign a weight of $W \gg 1$ to each edge adjacent to $X_0$, and a weight of $1$ to all other edges, and find a maximum-weight matching? This will indeed maximize the number of matched vertices of $X_0$, and subject to this, the number of matched vertices of $X$. But will it necessarily be a maximum cardinality matching in $G$?

Comment: In that case, you can try an opposite approach: given edges not adjacent to $X_0$ a weight of $1$, and those adjacent to $X_0$ a weight of $1+\epsilon$.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your question is "Find matching such that 1) it has the maximum number of edges 2) each vertex from $X_0$ has an adjacent edge in this matching"? Then you can just use Kuhn's algorithm, where you first process vertices from $X_0$ (if for some such vertex an augmented path wasn't found, such matching doesn't exist). This works since a saturated vertex will remain saturated. And yes, it'll find the maximum matching (since, well, Kuhn's algorithm is correct).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research, I found out that my question is a special case of the problem of [priority matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_matching). In this case there are two priority classes, $X_0$ and $X_1 := V\setminus X_0$. The goal is to find a matching that maximizes the number of saturated vertices in $X_0$, and subject to that, the number of saturated vertices in $X_1$. There are efficient algorithms that solve this problem for any number of priority classes. It is known that any priority matching is also a maximum-cardinality matching.